# AsyncResult not support in .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

I'm migrating MVC application into .NET Core that I had to make code changes to workaround `AsyncResult` class

> ERROR: The type or namespace name 'AsyncResult' couldn't not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
delegate void CopyMemoryStreamToFileDelegate(MemoryStream memorystream, string path);

public static bool SaveXmlIndentedAsync(XmlDocument doc, string path)
{
    XmlTextWriter writer = null;
    MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();

    CopyMemoryStreamToFileDelegate copyDelegate;


    Xmlattributes attribute = doc.CreateAtteibute("datetime");
    attribute.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(attribute);
    writer = new XmlTextWriter(memorystream, Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.IndentChar = '\t';
    writer.Formating = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);

    // Instantiated the call & callback delegates
    copydelegate = new CopyMemoryStreamToFileDelegate(CopyMemoryStreamToFile);

    //From here I'm calling below CopyCallback function 
    AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(CopyCallback);

}

private static void CopyCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    CopyMemoryStreamToFileDelegate copydelegate;
    try
    {
        //Get the asyncresult
        AsyncResult aResult = (AsyncResult)ar;// here I'm getting error Asyncresult 
                                                //Get the delegate that has fired the beginInvoke
        copyDelegate = aResult.AsyncDelegate as
        CopyMemoryStreamToFileDelegate;
        if (copyDelegate == null) return;

        //End Envoke
        copyDelegate.EndInvoke(ar);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.error(null, "copycallback: CopyMemoryStreamToFile throw ana exception", ex);
    }
}

private static void CopyMemoryStreamToFile(MemoryStream memorystream, string path)
{
FileStream filestream =null;
filestream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create);
byte[] buffer = memorystream.ToArray();
filestream.write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
}
```

After basic research I found asyncResult not exist in .net core. I'm trying to implement Using Task Run and async/await but not confident.could you please provide me the code change solution thanks.

Comment: After some basic research I understood AsyncResult is the too old code. Can you guys please suggest and provide me the solution please

Comment: Please help me any one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please fix your typos, like : `CopyMemoryStramToFileDelegate`, `CopyMemoreyStreamToFileDelegate`, `(AsyncReault)ar`, etc.

Comment: Ok thanx ... please provide me the solution

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. Your code does not compile because there are a couple of typos. Please fix them. After that we can help you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks .. I have update my code . Could you please check once

Comment: You need to provide some context. How do you call this?

Comment: And you never return a `bool` anywhere. If you want help quickly, ask a good well-documented question.

Comment: My only question and doubt how to work with AsyncResult in .net core . Since dot net core not supporting AsyncResult then what I have to use insted of it in the above code

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-delegate-begininvoke-calls-for-net-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly then you want to copy data from a `MemoryStream` into a file in an asynchronous fashion.

```cs
public static async Task SaveXmlIndentedAsync(XmlDocument doc, string path)
{
    XmlTextWriter writer = null;
    MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();

    Xmlattributes attribute = doc.CreateAtteibute("datetime");
    attribute.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(attribute);
    writer = new XmlTextWriter(memorystream, Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.IndentChar = '\t';
    writer.Formating = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);

    using var filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true);
    memorystream.Position = 0;
    await memorystream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

1. Open the FileStream for async write
2. Set the memoryStream's position to the beginning
3. Copy memoryStream into the filestream

I've changed the signature from `static bool` to `static async Task` to be able to use `await`

---

I haven't tested the code so, `FlushAsync` might be needed after `CopyToAsync`.